# React testing library not work with react router v6

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router

i start to learning react testing library a few days ago and i dont know how to make my tests works with react router v6. I have this two test below:

```
  describe('testing login page', () => {
  test('veryfy inputs and buttons in login page', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
    const userInput = screen.getByRole('textbox');
    expect(userInput).toBeInTheDocument();
```

```
  describe('testing Mine Page', () => {
  test('check table components', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/mina']}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/mina" element={<MineTable />} />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
    const pageTitle = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /mina/i });
    expect(pageTitle).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Only the first test works, the second don't render the page MineTable, keeps rendering the last page Login. It's like the history of the first test render remains. Someone can help me? I want to test every page component of my application.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to test your UI components on a route? Why can't you test `MineTable` alone?

Comment: When i try to test MineTable alone i still having the same error. Only the test of <LoginPage /> works,. When i try to test the component  <MineTable />  the render function of the react-testing-library not works and keeps rendering the LoginPage component instead the MineTable component

Comment: What does an isolated test for the `MineTable` component have to do with any other test rendering the `LoginPage` or any other component?

Comment: When i try test isolated i got this Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.Jest

Comment: So you only need to render the component into a ReactTree that has a router above it providing a routing context. There's no need to render `Routes` and `Route` components. You are using RTL so you can provide a wrapper to the `render` test utility. Would you like an example?

Comment: An example would be of great help, I'm still a little confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it seems that `MineTable` uses a `useNavigate` hook it needs a routing context provided to it higher in the ReactTree that it is being rendered into.

You only need to provide a routing context, there's no need to render routes and such. For this, you can wrap the component under test directly with the `MemoryRouter`.

```
describe('testing Mine Page', () => {
  test('check table components', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <MineTable />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
    const pageTitle = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /mina/i });
    expect(pageTitle).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

In fact, this pattern of needing to provide context is so common that RTL has a [`wrapper`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#wrapper) option you can use to provider a wrapper component that provides all the contexts a component uses, i.e. routing, themes, redux, locale translations, etc...

Example:

```
const RouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <MemoryRouter>
    {children}
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

...

```
import { RouterWrapper } from '../path/to/RouterWrapper';

describe('testing Mine Page', () => {
  test('check table components', () => {
    render(<MineTable />, { wrapper: RouterWrapper });
    const pageTitle = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /mina/i });
    expect(pageTitle).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

See [custom render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render) for more details.

Comment: What if you generate breadcrumbs based on route though?

Comment: @DanielvanderVelden What if? This sort of sounds like a good new SO post. If you do decide to make a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.